# "His dishonesty" vs "His being dishonest"

Tags: nouns, adjectives

My question is - which of the two phrases above sound better/worse?

- His dishonesty

OR

- His being dishonest

Actually, the question is not only about this particular noun/adjective pair, but extends to other verbs and nouns. Like in the following:

- Her selfishness  VS her being selfish
- Their irresponsibility VS their being irresponsible

Is there any difference in meaning between "his + noun" and "his being + adjective" ?

Answer (score 4):

English is a context-dependent language. Since you have provided none we could generalise and say:

'his dishonesty' refers to a trait.

'his being dishonest' refers to a single instance.

Context could override the above generalisation.